# Does PHP have the ability to turn a string such as "thirty-six" BACK to "36"?

Tags: php

This:

```
$a = new \NumberFormatter('en_UK', \NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
var_dump($a->format('36'));
```

Outputs:

```
thirty-six
```

If I *have* "thirty-six", "thirtysix" or "thirty six", can I turn that *back* into "36" with the same method somehow?

Note: I'm not talking about manually coding this for English, which I already have done in the past and could do again.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, using [`NumberFormatter::parse`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php):

```
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter('en_UK', \NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
var_dump($formatter->parse('thirty-six'));   // float(36)
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/l53Qh**

Note that this will only work for "thirty-six" in this case, as this is the proper way to write 36 in english.